# Returning from Excel custom function to Powershell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I cannot retrieve VBA function result from an Excel document into Powershell script.

*Powershell file*

```
$suite = "<some_path>"
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($suite)

$specs = $excel.Run("ThisWorkbook.ftp_specs")
IF([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($specs)) {            
    Write-Host "Your string is EMPTY or NULL"           
} else {            
    Write-Host "Your string is not EMPTY"           
}
```

*Excel file (in ThisWorkbook)*

```
Function ftp_specs()
    ftp_specs = "hello"
End Function
```

Powershell run result
`Your string is EMPTY or NULL`

MS Office VBA Reference states [Application.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run) returns a Variant.

Nothing i've seen on the web in the past few hours hints at anything relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need **ThisWorkbook** (?) namespace. Just use `Run` method with the function name. Like so:

```
$specs = $excel.Run("ftp_specs")
```

Comment: Thanks! Namespace was not the matter. Adding parentheses was: `$specs = $excel.Run("ThisWorkbook.ftp_specs()")`

Comment: No, you're right. Putting a custom function in ThisWorkbook and calling it as above invariably produces -2146826273. If I move the function to a module, your suggestion works. Weird, since i can call Sub couched in ThisWorkbook.